# Renaming sponsored link name in Android Tag

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags

As seen in this link [Android Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

Title of first sponsored link in Android Tag says

> Download the Android SDK

but on click of this link, it redirects to the page from which Android Studio can be downloaded for available platforms.

So in my opinion it should be renamed to

> Download Android Studio

as Android Studio is also an official/recommended IDE for Android Development.

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not able to find link with that title in [Android Tag Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)

Comment: @Tushar don't go in info tab, I have added link already check that

Comment: It took me to Newest Android Question. I can't find the link there too

Comment: @Tushar see the top in that page it will show `Sponsored link for this tag` and in that click on first link

Comment: @Stijn added screenshot

Comment: I am seeing this for an year now

Comment: It's removed by adblockers apparently.

Comment: @Stijn you can check by disabling adblocker if that is the issue

Comment: Still can't see it. Not enough freehand circles.

Comment: @CodyGray I can see it in all my browsers. Is it tag specific like I have asked most of my questions with android tag?

Comment: I see it, through noscript doesn't like it when I click it. it links to this https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: yes and it only provide links to download Android Studio and not Android sdk so I suggest that renaming

Comment: Yup it's the adblocker. @CodyGray Pause it and you will be able to see the sponsored links

Answer (score 13):

I work in the Ad Ops team at SO. Thanks for your post - we've brought your suggestion to the advertiser and will see if they'd like to update it. Thanks!